# Wix Publish element Condition Value

Tags: wix

In a Wix 'Publish' element:

```
          <Publish Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="PROGRAM_FILES_ROOT" Order="2">1</Publish>
```

What does the '1' do?

What does the Order="2" do?

I somewhat understand what Order="2" does, but I completely don't understand what the 1 does in the condition field.

I have scoured the internet trying to understand this, and I don't find any useful information.

I have tried experimenting by putting different values in where the '1' is.  I have found that leaving it out can generate an error, but I don't see any difference as long as there is a value there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `1` is used to represent "true". The text of the `Publish` element is the condition controlling the publishing of the event. For some reason, the Windows Installer engine needs a condition.

In WiX v4, this is handled for you. It will add the `1` if you don't specify a condition.

`Order` controls the order in which the events are published. The default order is the order that you place them in the file.

Comment: Is it a correct assumption that the events are evaluated in the order they are published, as a method of prioritizing multiple events whose conditions could evaluate to true at a given point?  (By experimentation, it looks like the higher 'Order' value gets priority.)

Comment: Yes. And the default order is the order of elements in the .wxs code, but the Order attribute overrides that if you want full control.